# Cufon jQuery Hover as a child element?

Tags: jquery, cufon

I'm having an odd problem with Jquery Hovers and Cufon.

My Nav is setup like this:

...

```
<li>
<a class="title" href="#">Title Text</a>
<a class="sub" href="#">Photo Gallery</a>
</li>
```

...

When I hover over the LI. I want the  a.sub to turn white (which works by adding a class because its normal text.) and I ant the a.title to turn green.

The problem is that the Title is replaced by Cufon. I know cufon can do hovers when the element is hovered over, but how do I trigger it when a parent item is hovered over?

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#bottomNav ul li').hover(

    function() {
        $("a.sub", this).addClass('hov');
        $("a.title", this).addClass('thov');
    }, 

    function() {
        $("a.sub", this).removeClass('hov');
        $("a.title", this).removeClass('thov');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy ... use

```
Cufon.refresh();
```

or for hover, its recommended you use the cufon hover method

```
Cufon.replace('.your-class', {hover: 'true'}, { fontFamily: 'FONT' });
```

Cheers!

Comment: thanks, ended up figuring it out but this is great info for anyone searching.

Comment: yes happens to me all the time too... I end up figuring it out myself... albeit I make sure to post the result to my question when I do find out... help other folks out here... cheers mate!